# Coming up with a system to capture Mailchimp signups and call one of our services before Mailchimp sends its welcome email

Tags: api, email, integration, mailchimp

I'm trying to come up with a solution for a product I'm developing. The process for users is ideally as follows:

- User signs up to form created with mailchimp
- Mailchimp stores parameters from form
- Our system generates a custom GIF and URL to this GIF using parameters from mailchimp sign up form
- Mailchimp sends a welcome email to the user who signed up with the custom GIF URL generated in our system once the GIF has been generated, creating a seamless flow.

This process cannot be done in something like Zapier or Make as we are creating a solution inside of our product for users to use to insert custom GIFs for each signup in Mailchimp into their welcome emails.